# How to export copyright notice in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I've set a default copyright notice in Android Studio, following [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-and-updating-copyright-notice.html).

Now I want to export the copyright profile I've created into a format that I can place in VCS, so I can share it with my team. How can I do this?

Comment: You can find your Copyright Profiles under the \.idea\copyright directory of your project. You can import those files in different projects.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot you need to paste the copyright notice into your copyright settings.

Go to File/Settings

[image]

Editor/Copyright/Copyright Profiles

[image]

Then select green +, create new copyright profile

[image]

Grab [whatever copyright notice](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) you want to use and paste it into here:

[image]

You'll see that there is provision to replace old copyright.

Then go back to the Copyright selection and add your new copyright profile:

[image]

Create a new class:

[image]

And you will see your copyright at the top.

Please note to **apply** all changes and that you can control which files your copyright notice will be applied to.

Comment: I know how to set and import it, but my question is how to export this copyright notice, so I can share this setting with my teammates.

Comment: Sorry, Can you show me how to export the copyright notice, because I can only find the import button in android stuido...

Comment: Got you. But can I export them and other developers can just import it instead of following the steps above. I would like to wait for better answer if any.